# How to use CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast in CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I've been googling for a long time & I can't find a single tutorial on how to use this property on iOS. Can someone please post a small tutorial or a link to one? I would really, really appreciate it!

I'm using this code:

```
CBMutableCharacteristic *myCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:myUUID
                                                                                   properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast
                                                                                        value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
```

This crashes with an exception: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast is not allowed'`

Comment: I am using `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite|CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse` and this exception is being thrown... :(

Comment: Oops I figured out my issue - I had to use CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's documentation on the broadcast Characteristic Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCharacteristicProperties)

> This property is not allowed for local characteristics published via the addService: method of the CBPeripheralManager class. This means that you cannot use this property when you initialize a new CBMutableCharacteristic object via the initWithType:properties:value:permissions: method of the CBMutableCharacteristic class.